# Subgroups of finitely generated abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

> Let $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_{{p_1}^{k_1}}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{{p_2}^{k_2}}\oplus \dots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{{p_n}^{k_n}}$.
>
> Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.
>
> Does $H$ necessarily have the form $H\cong \mathbb{Z}_{{p_1}^{l_1}}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{{p_2}^{l_2}}\oplus \dots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{{p_n}^{l_n}}$, where $l_i\leq k_i$?

If so, why? And if not, are there any counterexamples?

Comment: Are the $p_i$ all primes? all different?

Comment: Yes they are all primes, not necessarily different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. $H$ is another finite abelian group, so by the classification of finitely generated abelian groups, it must be isomorphic to a group of the form you've given. The fact that the decomposition of $H$ has the same primes but with possibly smaller exponents $l_i$ is very easy to see. Just consider orders of elements of $H$ and remember that they're elements of $G$ too.

The really important thing to realize is that the isomorphism $H\cong \mathbb{Z}_{{p_1}^{l_1}}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{{p_2}^{l_2}}\oplus \dots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{{p_n}^{l_n}}$ need not respect the isomorphism $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_{{p_1}^{k_1}}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{{p_2}^{k_2}}\oplus \dots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{{p_n}^{k_n}}$ in the following sense. The subgroup of $H$ identified with $\mathbb{Z}_{{p_i}^{l_i}}$ need not be a subgroup of the $\mathbb{Z}_{{p_i}^{k_i}}$-subgroup of $G$. For instance, take $G = \mathbb Z_4 \oplus \mathbb Z_4$ and let $H = \langle (2, 2)\rangle$. Then $H \cong \mathbb Z_2$, but it is not a subgroup of either direct summand of $G$.

Comment: "*The fact that the decomposition of $H$ has the same primes but with possibly smaller exponents $l_i$ is very easy to see.*" I won't be so sure.

Comment: @user26857 To be fair, I did give the hint to look at the order of each element of $H$. The proof of the claim follows from doing just that since $H$ and $G$ are finite groups. Since OP seems satisfied with my answer, I'm not sure what you're trying to prove here.

Comment: I'm proving that you are not proving anything, just leaving an useless hint. (The fact that the OP accepted your answer doesn't change my opinion.)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is positive.

For every prime $p$ the $p$-torsion of $H$ is a subgroup of the $p$-torsion of $G$, so you can reduce the problem to the case $p_1=\cdots=p_n=p$.

Notice that $p^kG$ is a direct sum of $n_k=|\{i:k_i>k\}|$ cyclic groups, and similarly $p^kH$ is a direct sum of $m_k=|\{i:l_i>k\}|$ cyclic groups. Since $p^kH\subseteq p^kG$ for every $k\ge1$ we can conclude that $m_k\le n_k$ for all $k\ge 1$ as soon as we show that $m_0\le n_0$, and then this is enough to get $l_i\le k_i$ for all $i$. But $G\simeq\mathbb Z^n/K$ where $K$ is a free abelian group of rank $n$, so $H=F/K$ where $K\subseteq F\subseteq\mathbb Z^n$. Then $F$ is free of rank $n$, so $H$ is a direct sum of at most $n$ cyclic modules.